# Debugging protractor tests which are started with Angular CLI's `ng e2e`

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

How can a protractor test be debugged using Angular 6+ running with `ng e2e`.

I set `debug: true` in the `e2e/protractor.conf.js` file. When calling `browser.pause()` in the test I get an error and the hint, that I should use the `debugger;` keyword. Usign has no effect though.

Example code:

```
it('the user-menu should be present', () => {
  page.navigateTo();
  browser.pause();
  //debugger;
  let elem = page.getUserIconMenuButton();
  expect(elem.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This is the warning I get:

```
***********************************************************
* WARNING: _debugger module not available on Node.js 8    *
* and higher.                                             *
*                                                         *
* Use 'debugger' keyword instead:                       *
* https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md                               
***********************************************************
C:\...\node_modules\protractor\built\debugger\debuggerCommons.js:14
  throw e;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '_debugger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\protractor\built\debugger\debuggerCommons.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I tried to follow the instructions in the ling provided ( https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md ) but this isn't really a help.

Has anybody a Tutorial on how to setup debugging of e2e tests using Angular-CLI?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you had found any solution to the problem. But I found some help here.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307#issuecomment-386112285

For Node v8+:-

- Set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your `protractor.conf.js`
- Update your `tsconfig.e2e.json`'s `target` as `"target": "es2017"`
- Use **async/await** . For eg-

  ````
   it('should greet the named user', async function() {
     await browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
     await element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
   });```
  ````

It fixed my problem. Hope it helps you too.
Please share if you find some other solution too.

Comment: Is it not possible to debug if we use promises in my code. I mean if I do not use aync-await what is my option?

Comment: @HarishaKP I've never actually tried, that, as I want my code to be much cleaner and readable. I should work I guess, but you have to test it.

Comment: Looks like debug becomes hell if we use promises. I tries and decided to use async/await as much as possible.